# Node js app running inside container opens user's web browser

Tags: node.js, docker, browser, docker-container

I need an option to open user's default web browser from node js app which is running inside docker container. I need to know that to implement OAuth flow.

I know that I can do it by opening new tab on the client side, but I don't have this option for other reasons.

Comment: I won’t give any code examples because this question is not about code. I require simple answers it’s possible doing this or simple it’s not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with docker container, but for just straight nodejs, this works for me:

```
//  start browser
if (opSys == "Win64")
    command = ("start http://localhost:8000/init"); // Win64
else if (opSys == "MacOS")
    command = ("open http://localhost:8000/init");  // MacOS
else
    command = ("xdg-open http://localhost:8000/init"); // Linux
exec (command, function (error, stdout, stderr) 
    {
    if (error)
        {
        console.log ("command: ", command);
        console.log ("error: ", stderr);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes this is an example how to open web browser on different os. The problem with app running in Docker container is that, it is isolated from User os. It has it’s own os and running these command will open browser in container but not on User machine.